# Foreach loop in XML generator not breaking

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I am trying to generate XML, but the loop isn't breaking. Here is a part of the code:

```
@key = 0
@cont.each do |pr|
  xml.product {
    @key += 1
    puts @key.to_s
    begin
      @main = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@url+pr['href'], "User-Agent" => "Ruby/#{RUBY_VERSION}","From" => "foo@bar.invalid", "Referer" => "http://www.ruby-lang.org/"))
    rescue
      puts "rescue"
      next
    end
    puts pr['href']
    puts @key.to_s
    break  //this break doesn't work
    #something else
  }
end
```

Most interesting is that in the final generated XML file, `break` worked. The file contains only one product, but on the console `@key` was printed fully, which means the `foreach` loop doesn't break.

Could it be a Nokogiri XML-specific error, because of open brackets in the head of the loop?

Comment: First, where you initialize `@url`, second - what is consist in the `@cont` ?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 1):

In general I think how you're going about trying to generate the XML is confused. Don't convolute your code any more than necessary; Instead of starting to generate some XML then aborting it inside the block because you can't find the page you want, grab the pages you want first, *then* start processing.

I'd move the `begin`/`rescue` block outside the XML generation. Its existence inside the XML generation block results in poor logic and questionable practices of using `next` and `break`. Instead I'd recommend something like this untested code:

```
@main = []
@cont.each do |pr|
  begin
    @main << Nokogiri::HTML(
      open(@url + pr['href'])
    )
  rescue
    puts 'rescue'
    next
  end
end

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.root {
    xml.products {
      @main.each do |m|
        xml.product {
          xml.id_ m.at('id').text
          xml.name m.at('name').text
        }
      end
    }
  }
end
puts builder.to_xml
```

Which makes it easy to see that the code is keying off being able to retrieve a page.

This code is untested because we have no idea what your input values are or what your output should look like. Having valid input, expected output and a working example of your code that demonstrates the problem is essential if you want help debugging a problem with your code.

The use of `@url + pr['href']` isn't generally a good idea. Instead use the URI class to build up the URL for you. URI handles encoding and ensures the URI is valid.

Comment: VTC? Dunno what that is. Virtual Trouble Coaxing?

Comment: I voted to close initially, and then the question bugged me enough I had to say something. I still think the question is off-topic because it's not runnable and doesn't have sufficient info for us to help the OP's question, but at least the OP has a better shot at writing something that is maintainable.

Comment: Fair enough :)  It showed up in the review queue, which how I saw it.  Great answer, by the way.

Comment: Thanks. I go nuts when I see code jumping in and out of what should be two chunks of logic. Makes my head hurt.